# Selenium not getting different URLs

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using Selenium in Python to scrape a site that loads Javascript
Here's my code:
[https://gist.github.com/elliotmartin/f9cb5021655f913f250b08f39a14dc9d][1]

For some reason as I loop over different URLs the get_boards function is returning the exact same results.

For example:
This URL:

> https://playhearthstone.com/en-us/community/leaderboards/?region=US&leaderboardId=STD&seasonId=73&page=1

```
Gets:
```

> {'FAST44': '1', 'Mesmile': '2', 'Pizza': '3', 'Stacker': '4',
>   'Jackpot': '5', 'Gavin': '6', 'Monsanto': '7', 'VictorFalcon': '8',
>   'Cantelope': '9', 'Rozz': '10', 'molino': '11', 'Eddie': '12',
>   'SwitchSSB': '13', 'Rey': '14', 'wabeka': '15', 'Enrico': '16',
>   'TheRabbin': '17', 'Jalexander': '18', 'Itim': '19', 'Jay': '20',
>   'DuVlad': '21', 'Staz': '22', 'BanditKeith': '23', 'Akatsu': '24',
>   'Montius': '25'}

And this URL:

> https://playhearthstone.com/en-us/community/leaderboards/?region=US&leaderboardId=STD&seasonId=73&page=2

Also gets:

> {'FAST44': '1', 'Mesmile': '2', 'Pizza': '3', 'Stacker': '4',
>   'Jackpot': '5', 'Gavin': '6', 'Monsanto': '7', 'VictorFalcon': '8',
>   'Cantelope': '9', 'Rozz': '10', 'molino': '11', 'Eddie': '12',
>   'SwitchSSB': '13', 'Rey': '14', 'wabeka': '15', 'Enrico': '16',
>   'TheRabbin': '17', 'Jalexander': '18', 'Itim': '19', 'Jay': '20',
>   'DuVlad': '21', 'Staz': '22', 'BanditKeith': '23', 'Akatsu': '24',
>   'Montius': '25'}

But none of those values are even present anywhere in the HTML loaded by the Javascript on the second URL.

So selenium must not be reloading the new URL? I'm very new to Selenium, so I think that's where my issue lies.

[

> 1]:
>   https://gist.github.com/elliotmartin/f9cb5021655f913f250b08f39a14dc9d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
driver.get('https://playhearthstone.com/en-us/api/community/leaderboardsData?region=US&leaderboardId=STD&seasonId=73')

rows = driver.execute_script("""
  return JSON.parse(document.body.innerText).leaderboard.rows.reduce(function(acc, o){
    acc[o.accountid] = o.rank
    return acc
  }, {})
""")
```

I'm just getting the api data from the endpoint and returning it to python

Comment: This worked! Would you be able to explain a bit more about what the snippet you posted does? Or simply a link or two to relevant documentation?

Comment: It loads the json endpoint in the browser then parses it. The reduce function gets it into the same format you had in the question.